# Copy specific files from different directories without changing file extension

Tags: bash, find, cp

I have a bunch of image files named as `1.jpg` in several directories I want to copy that into another.
I tried using the below command (consider 100 folders)

```
find folder/{1..100} -type f -name '1.*' -exec cp --backup=numbered "{}" folder/new/ \;
```

but the file extension get changed as below

```
1.jpg.~1~
1.jpg.~2~
1.jpg.~3~
...
```

I am expecting my output should look something like below

```
1.~1~.jpg
1.~2~.jpg
1.~3~.jpg
...

(or)

1(1).jpg
1(2).jpg
1(3).jpg
...
```

Note: I am using `{1..100}` so that folder order starts from `1, 2, 3, 4...100` and not as `1, 10, 11,...100, 2, 20, 21, 22...`

Is there any way I could find and copy images without changing the file extension?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Since you want to define your own numbering scheme for the backup, I suggest that instead of running `cp`, you run a shell script which calculates the new file name, if there is already a file of the same name in the destination directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to use the subfolder name (number) as a suffix to the new
file name, would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

folder="folder"                 # directory name
base="1"                        # basename of the jpg file
ext="jpg"                       # extention of the jpg file
new="new"                       # directory name for the "new" files

mkdir -p "$folder/$new"         # create "new" directory if nonexistent

while IFS= read -r -d "" f; do
    n=${f#*$folder/}; n=${n%/$base.$ext}
    echo cp -i -- "$f" "$folder/$new/$base($n).$ext"
done < <(find "$folder" -type f -regex "$folder/[0-9]+/$base\.$ext" -print0)
```

- `find "$folder" -type f -regex "$folder/[0-9]+/$base\.$ext"` finds
  all numbered folders which contains "1.jpg". You do not have to specify
  the range between 1 and 100.
- `-print0` option uses a null character to delimit filenames. It is useful
  to protect filenames which may contain special characters such as blank
  characters.
- The output of `find` command, matched filenames delimited by null characters,
  is redirected to the `read` command within the `while` loop.
- The `-d ""` option to the `read` command splits the input on null characters
  corresponding to `-print0`.
- `n=${f#*$folder/}; n=${n%/$base.$ext}` assigns `n` to the subfolder name
  which contains the jpg file.
- `"$folder/$new/$base($n).$ext"` constructs the new filename rearranging
  the substrings.

If the output of the `echo` command looks okay, drop `echo`.

Comment: It worked perfectly as I expected, Thanks a lot. 

Answer (score 1):

Do you accept a solution in two times?

1. Run your `find` command
2. Run this command:

```bash
for f in folder/new/*.~*~; do
  idx="${f##*.}";
  new=${f%.${idx}};
  idx="${idx//\~/}";
  ext="${new##*.}";
  new="${new%.${ext}}";
  new="${new}(${idx}).${ext}";
  echo mv "$f" "$new";
done
```

Only based on bash remove `%`, `#`, `%%` and `##` matching patterns.

1. get index pattern from original filename (f)
2. new filename (new) is original filename without index extension (~*~)
3. remove `~` characters in index token (idx)
4. get original filename extension (ext)
5. remove original filename extension in new filename
6. create new filename (with format as you want)
7. rename original filename to new filename

Notes:

- Remove new line characters if you want (just here for presentation)
- After test, remove `echo` before `mv` command.